# Blackberry Workspaces

Tags: python, rest, blackberry, workspace

Hello I am trying to download a file using Python from Blackberry Workspaces. I couldn't find much help online on trying to connect using Blackberry-Workspaces python Library. Any help is much appreciated

I tried connecting using Requests but I am not sure if I connected to it correctly. I imported blackberry workspace package but I am not sure how to use it to establish connection.

Comment: Looks like the library is not actively developed and doesn't have documentation. You have two options: 1. go through libraries code and figure out how it works. 2. Use API manually (e.x. with requests) and provide your attempts and what didn't work.